# how to create 2D array in javascript (dynamic)

Tags: javascript

```js
var array1 = ["james","bob"];
var array2 = ["name","age"];
```

i had created let us say two arrays array1 and array2. what i'm doing is now for every element in array1 i want a new array of length 5 for that. for example for "james" i want an array of length 5 and for "bob" i want array if length 5 only. Also array1 is dynamic, not static. How to achieve that?

Comment: Your question is unclear - please specify the expected output. ie, why does "james" produce an array of 5 elements and bob *also* an array of 5 elements (is everything 5 elements??) What has `array2` got to do with this question?

Comment: Almost sounds like you want an object...

Comment: Yes, Its seems you need and object array. Please clarify your question. You can create array of objects and then assign "james" key a new array.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: what i'm doing is for every entry in array1 i am getting values from the user as input and pushing that object as a whole in an array, say in array2. So for every user/entry in array1, array2 must have only 5 objects in it

Comment: Why are you doing this with 2 arrays? ANd that has nothing to do with a 2D array so your title is misleading. You should probably be doing it with an array of objects as the other comments mention! PLease provide a [mcve] specifying the *actual* problem!

Comment: it will be done only with 2D array. no need to downvote ok.

Comment: for every entry in one array i want to create array of length 5 that's it. maybe now you will understand

Comment: Sorry, its just a badly worded and asked question. It deserves its down and close votes in its current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). `Reduce` will iterate for each name in your `array1` and you have aggregator `newarr` where code will keep inserting an array of 5 elements using `newarr.push(Array(5))`(Array(5) is a constructor to create an array of 5 elements);

In case you want to give default value you can use [`array#fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```js
var array1 = ["james","bob"];

var newarr = array1.reduce((newarr, name) => {
  newarr.push(Array(5));
  return newarr;
},[]);

console.log(newarr);
```

Comment: yes that's the kind of thing i wanted but just can you explain a bit or provide in a more explainatory way

Comment: I have added some explanation. In case, it is still unclear, do comment.

Comment: i had posted the code, i think u better understand now

Comment: `dc.store_name_array.reduce((newarr,name)=>{
         newarrpush(Array(5));
         return newarr;
     },[]
     );` Your reduce should look like this.
     }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150586/discussion-between-hassan-imam-and-piyush).